# AngularJS select in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a list of `<select>`'s with `ng-repeat`, there is a `item.quantity` that I need to be selected in each select in the list, I have tried several ways without success.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

   <select ng-model="selCartQuantity">
     <option index="1" ng-selected="item.quantity=='1'">1</option>
     <option index="2" ng-selected="item.quantity=='2'">2</option>
     <option index="3" ng-selected="item.quantity=='3'">3</option>
     <option index="4" ng-selected="item.quantity=='4'">4</option>
     <option index="5" ng-selected="item.quantity=='5'">5</option>
   </select>

</div>
```

Comment: is `item.quantity` a numeric or string value?

Comment: it's numeric, thank you @salniro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller you put the following code (of course you change $scope.items to your actual object )

```js
$scope.items = [{name:'aaaaa'},{name:'bbbbb'}];
$scope.options= [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.items.forEach(function(item,index){
  
  item.selCartQuantity= $scope.options[0];
  
 });


and in the html markup you put the following
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

 <select ng-model="item.selCartQuantity" ng-options="option for option in options"></select>

</div>
```

`

---

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend checking out the [angular select driective](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), as you shouldn't have to do the ng-repeat at all. The select directive will automatically set the selected option to be what you have in your model.